# Moving text after canvas rotation

Tags: android, android-canvas

After I successfully rotate the canvas and draw text in my Custom View's onDraw method, I want to now move this text some more on the canvas however with my current approach all the X and Y coordinates seem to be inverted due to the canvas rotation. I want to figure out a way to move the text position in line with the finger position on screen even though the canvas has been rotated. This rotation can be changed dynamically so it is not a static rotation of the canvas that has been made. Currently this is how I draw my text :

```
    canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(degree,cenX,cenY);
        canvas.drawText(mText, textX, textY + yoffset, mTextPaint);
    canvas.restore();
```

cenX and cenY represents the coordinates of the mid point between the 2 finger points.
textX and textY relate to the touched X and Y positions on screen. yoffset is set to 0 for the moment. mText is the text to draw. The movement of the text before rotation is as expected the correct x,y coordinates, however after rotating the text no longer draws at the expected x,y coordinates being touched on screen.

Comment: Did you able to solve this out?